# Issue with Ivy custome resolver

Tags: ivy

Can anyone help me with creating custom ivy resolver. I wish to extend URLResolver, such that it will have a new class say called ProxyURLResolver where i will set the proxy, resolve the artifact and then remove the proxy setting. I tried extending URLResolver directly before calling setRepository method and reseting after and had typedef as well in ivysettings.xml, but it didn't worked. Can you please help me by telling the exact steps that i need to follow to create new cutom resolver?

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't answer your question but perhaps it would be easier to set up a local caching proxy and then use a standard [ibiblio](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/ibiblio.html) resolver in ivy.

The following products can be used:

- [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/)
- [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.org/products.php)
- [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/)